# Insert xml element as nested element using ElementTree API in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have to modify an XML document. I am using Python and ElementTree API for it. But I have hit a roadblock.
The present structure is like:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <...>
            </...>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

And I have to add a sub element B2 to B which is a parent to C such that the new structure is:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <B2>
            <C>
                <...>
                </...>
            </C>
        </B2>
    </B>
</A>
```

Right now when I try to add a sub element it is creating one but not as parent of C, the new one is coming as a separate element inside B.
Can anyone help me and give me pointers as to how I can create a sub element as a parent of another element ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***how I can create a sub element as a parent of another element ?***: You can't, you have to remove `C`, insert `B2` and. add `C` as child of `B2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unwise way to use string concatenation for your reference only.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <...>
            </...>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
c = doc.select('C')
html = doc.html[0:c._start]+"<B2>"+c.outerHtml+"</B2>"+doc.html[c._end:]
print(html)
```

Result:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <B2><C>
            <...>
            </...>
        </C></B2>
    </B>
</A>
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/element.py